# Can someone help me fine-tune my **else if** statement in this code?

Tags: arrays, c, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a code that checks the user entered password against a **Password Format** e.g. "`L$$222ee`" (first letter uppercase, followed by two special characters, followed by three digits and finally two lowercase letters). My code is working fine; I just want to refine the **else if** statement. Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
//format required: L$$222ee
int main(){
    char pass[8];
    printf("Enter password:\n");
    gets(pass);
    if(strlen(pass)<8){
        printf("Password is too short...!!!\n");
    }
    else if(isupper(pass[0]) && ((!isalpha(pass[1]) && !isalpha(pass[2])) && !isdigit(pass[1]) && !isdigit(pass[2])) 
    && (isdigit(pass[3]) && isdigit(pass[4]) && isdigit(pass[5])) && (isalpha(pass[6]) 
    && isalpha(pass[7]))){
        printf("Password is compliant");
    }
    else{
        printf("Error: password is not compliant with the format!!!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `((!isalpha(pass[1]) && !isalpha(pass[2])) && !isdigit(pass[1]) && !isdigit(pass[2]))` can be replaced by `!(isalnum(pass[1]) && !(isalnum(pass[2]))`

Comment: @IrAM thanks for the help, its working fine and looking better now

Comment: Are you open for a whole new way of doing things? (Basically the password format should be loosened. It's ugly because it's just not a good idea in the first place.)

Comment: @Joshua i would've agreed for sure, but someone else has given me the task with the said password format. I have to fulfil their requirements.

Comment: See [Why `gets()` is too dangerous to be used — ever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) and never, ever use `gets()`.

Comment: You need a string of 8 characters plus a terminating null byte — those will not fit into `char pass[8];`. It needs to be at least `char pass[9];`. However, you should allow people to enter overlong passwords and reject them. Consider: `char pass[2048]; if (fgets(pass, sizeof(pass), stdin) == 0) { …EOF… } pass[strcspn(pass, "\n")] = '\0';` and then check the result for length != 8 (it could be longer or shorter and both are invalid), and then for content. The expression using `strcspn()` safely zaps the newline at the end of the entered password — `fgets()` keeps the newline; `gets()` doesn't.

Comment: You should probably loop over the 'guide string' (`"L$$222eee"`) and over the submitted password in tandem, checking that the class of character in the password matches the class required by the guide string.  `char guide[] = "L$$222eee"; for (int i = 0, len = strlen(guide); i < len; i++) { int rc = 0; switch (guide[i]) { case 'L': rc = isupper(pass[i]); break; case 'e': rc = islower(pass[i]); break; case '2': rc = isdigit(pass[i]); break; case '$': rc = ispunct(pass[i]); break; default: /* internal error */ abort(); } if (rc == 0) { …report mismatch… } }` or thereabouts. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ Strictly, the calls to `isxxxxx()` should use `isupper((unsigned char)pass[i])` with the cast ensuring that a valid value is passed to the function.  You'll probably be OK, but compilers set fussy would legitimately complain on many systems.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Not so "strictly", if your platform / compiler uses signed chars...

Comment: As for gets(), note that this function is no longer even part of the standard library. It was so toxic that it has been *removed* from the language wholesale.

Comment: Eh, it was only flagged as obsolete 25 years ago. We apparently can't expect all C teachers out there to adapt that fast. It's at least a good thing that people too incompetent to do any form of job can be hired as C teachers instead of being unemployed. They can at least check that all students are present and such tasks, even if they can't be trusted with any form of teaching.

Answer (score 2):

Since all these ctype.h functions have the same format `int func (int)`, you can take advantage of that to create a look-up table corresponding to all checks that need to be done. The advantage of a look-up table is that it's much easier to maintain than a fairly unreadable chain of `&&`.

First create a function typedef identical to the ctype functions: `typedef int ctype_func_t (int);`

Then make a struct to be used in the look-up table. Store string index, the true or false condition of the result, and the function itself:

```
typedef struct
{
  size_t         index;
  bool           cond;
  ctype_func_t*  check_func;
} check_t;
```

A look-up table can then be created as:

```
const check_t fmt_check [] =
{
  {0, true,  isupper },
  {1, false, isalpha },
  {2, false, isalpha },
  {1, false, isdigit },
  {2, false, isdigit }, 
  {3, true,  isdigit },
  {4, true,  isdigit },
  {5, true,  isdigit },
  {6, true,  isalpha },
  {7, true,  isalpha },
};
```

The order isn't important, add or remove format requirements as you please. The complete function for this would look like:

```
int ispwcorrect (const char pw[8])
{
  typedef int ctype_func_t (int);
  typedef struct
  {
    size_t         index;
    bool           cond;
    ctype_func_t*  check_func;
  } check_t;

  const check_t fmt_check [] =
  {
    {0, true,  isupper },
    {1, false, isalpha },
    {2, false, isalpha },
    {1, false, isdigit },
    {2, false, isdigit }, 
    {3, true,  isdigit },
    {4, true,  isdigit },
    {5, true,  isdigit },
    {6, true,  isalpha },
    {7, true,  isalpha },
  };
  
  for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof fmt_check/sizeof *fmt_check; i++)
  {
    unsigned char ch = pw[ fmt_check[i].index ];
    
    if((bool)fmt_check[i].check_func(ch) != fmt_check[i].cond)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }  
  return true;
}
```

This should be fairly self-explanatory, it calls ctype functions through a function pointer in a loop with a specific string index character as parameter. Then checks against a true/false condition. The check stops as soon as there is a mismatch.

The cast to `bool` after calling each ctype function is necessary, since they return zero or non-negative `int`. So comparing a `bool` against such a non-zero `int` won't work, since == will promote the `bool` parameter to an `int`.

This should vastly outperform regex, but will be slightly slower than the raw if-else.

---

Unrelated to your question, you also have a severe bug here: `char pass[8];`. There is no room for the null terminator, so you can't store `"L$$222ee"` inside `pass`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, on Unix systems, you can use the [`regex.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/regex.h.html) module, which supports the [POSIX basic regular expression syntax](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html).
In this case, the example will look like this:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>

//format required: L$$222ee
char pattern[] = "[[:upper:]][^[:alnum:]]\\{2\\}[[:digit:]]\\{3\\}[[:lower:]]\\{2\\}";
int main(){
    char pass[8];
    printf("Enter password:\n");
    gets(pass);

    regex_t regex;
    int ret;
    char msgbuf[100];

    if(strlen(pass)<8){
        printf("Password is too short...!!!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // Compile regular expression
    ret = regcomp(&regex, pattern, 0);
    if (ret) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex\n");
        return 0;
    }
    /* Execute regular expression */
    ret = regexec(&regex, pass, 0, NULL, 0);
    if (!ret) {
        printf("Password is compliant");
    }
    else if (ret == REG_NOMATCH) {
        printf("Error: password is not compliant with the format!!!\n");
    }
    else {
        regerror(ret, &regex, msgbuf, sizeof(msgbuf));
        fprintf(stderr, "Regex match failed: %s\n", msgbuf);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me help you, not with giving you an answer, but showing you how you can make that "else-if" clause more readable, this is what you have:

```
else if(isupper(pass[0]) && ((!isalpha(pass[1]) && !isalpha(pass[2])) && !isdigit(pass[1]) && !isdigit(pass[2])) 
    && (isdigit(pass[3]) && isdigit(pass[4]) && isdigit(pass[5])) && (isalpha(pass[6]) 
    && isalpha(pass[7])))
```

You can "re-write" this (just using some indentation, newlines and comments), like this:

```
else if( isupper(pass[0]) &&                             // 0   : Must be upper 
         ( ( !isalpha(pass[1]) && !isalpha(pass[2])) &&  // 1,2 : both should not be alpha
           !isdigit(pass[1]) &&                          // 1   : should not be digit
           !isdigit(pass[2])                             // 2   : should not be digit
           ) && 
         ( isdigit(pass[3]) &&                           // 3   : Must be digit
           isdigit(pass[4]) &&                           // 4   : Must be digit
           isdigit(pass[5])                              // 5   : Must be digit
         ) && 
         ( isalpha(pass[6]) &&                           // 6   : Must be alpha
           isalpha(pass[7])                              // 7   : Must be alpha
         )
       )
```

It takes some extra writing and editing, but it makes the whole thing more readable, comprehensible and as a result, easily maintainable (seen the fact that rules about passwords are rapidly changing, maintainability of such functions is quite important).

By the way, just by looking at this, you easily realise that you can re-write the part about `pass[1]` and `pass[2]`:

Currently:

```
        ( ( !isalpha(pass[1]) && !isalpha(pass[2])) &&  // 1,2 : both should not be alpha
           !isdigit(pass[1]) &&                          // 1   : should not be digit
           !isdigit(pass[2])                             // 2   : should not be digit
           ) &&
```

Proposal:

```
          ( !isalpha(pass[1]) && !isalpha(pass[2]) ) &&  // 1,2 : both should not be alpha
          ( !isdigit(pass[1]) && !isdigit(pass[2]) ) &&  // 1,2 : both should not be digit
```